# Double checking for existence a map element?

Tags: java, dictionary

In the code I'm working on right now I came across the following piece:

```
PartnerReportItem item = (map.get(partnerId) == null) ? null
    : map.get(partnerId).get(platform); //1, check for existence

if (item == null) {
    item = new PartnerReportItem();
    item.setPlatform(platform);
    item.setPartnerId(partnerId);
    item.setPartnerEmail(partner.getEmail());
    item.setPartnerPaymentDetails(paymentDetails);
    item.setPartnerCoef(partner.getCoef());
    item.setExchangeMap(exchangeMap);

    if (!map.containsKey(partnerId)) //2, double check for existence??
        map.put(partnerId, new HashMap<Platform, PartnerReportItem>());
    map.get(partnerId).put(platform, item);
}
```

I'm confused by `//1` and `//2` because I think //2 is unneccesary here. We've already checked if the element with `partnerId` existed in the map. May I not get a hidden idea?

Comment: It might be redundant (`//2` would be always true), but in a multithreaded environment a new value might be added to the map in between.

Comment: @GáborBakos I'm working on a web-application so, there is the multithreading environment. Would you suggest to leave this piece of code out?

Comment: I would not remove the second check. It's intended.

Comment: It's a necessary check. However this is bad code because the item can be null for two reasons. You better have to split it into two parts, to make the intent more clear (as we can see it's confusing you).

Comment: @GáborBakos It is not correct, that `//2` would always be true.

Comment: You are right. It is also possible it was assigned to the value `null` before for that key.

Answer (score 4):

the item might be null because the map.get did not return anything (the outer map does not exist) or because the inner map does not contain the requested object. Therefor, a second check is performed to detect the actual reason `item` became null.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a map within a map.

```
PartnerReportItem item = (map.get(partnerId) == null) ? null : map.get(partnerId).get(platform);
```

If `item` is not null, this means that `partnerId` is found in the outer map and `platform` is found in the inner map.

However, if `item` is null, it's still possible that `partnerId` key exists in the outer map, which means the containsKey check if necessary.

Comment: :) same answer as mine

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers stated, you need to keep this check. However this is a bad coding actually, because there are multiple reasons which are unrelated for the `PartnerReportItem` instance to be null (and hence the second check in the first if statement).

You better have to split it to make the intent more clear (and avoid confusions when others are reading your code).

```
Map<Platform, PartnerReportItem> innerMap = map.get(partnerId);
if(innerMap == null) {
    innerMap = new HashMap<Platform, PartnerReportItem>();
    innerMap.put(partnerId, createPartnerReportItem(...));
} else {
    PartnerReportItem item = innerMap.get(partnerId);
    if(item == null) {
        innerMap.put(partnerId, createPartnerReportItem(...));
    }
}
```

or another variant:

```
Map<Platform, PartnerReportItem> innerMap = map.get(partnerId);
if(innerMap == null) {
    innerMap = new HashMap<Platform, PartnerReportItem>();
}
PartnerReportItem item = innerMap.get(partnerId);
if(item == null) {
    innerMap.put(partnerId, createPartnerReportItem(...));
}
```

The point is that the programmer who wrote this ternary nested statement though that it would be less code but at the end, you see that it's just confusing. Always write readable code!